# AJAX\JQUERY: Update MYSQL database with form data without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ok, so I've gotten most of this thing done.. Now comes, for me, the hard part. This is untreaded territory for me.

How do I update my mysql database, with form data, without having the page refresh? I presume you use AJAX and\or Jquery to do this- but I don't quite grasp the examples being given.

Can anybody please tell me how to perform this task within this context?

So this is my form:

```
 <form name="checklist" id="checklist" class="checklist">
        <?php // Loop through query results   
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                  {
                  $entry = $row['Entry'];
                  $CID = $row['CID'];
                  $checked =$row['Checked'];
                 // echo $CID;
                  echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"$entry\" name=\"textfield$CID;\" id=\"textfield$CID;\" onchange=\"showUser(this.value)\" />";
                  echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"\" name=\"checkbox$CID;\" id=\"checkbox$CID;\"  value=\"$checked\"".(($checked == '1')? ' checked="checked"' : '')."  />";
                  echo "<br>";
                  }
        ?> 
        <div id="dynamicInput"></div>
        <input type="submit" id="checklistSubmit" name="checklistSubmit" class="checklist-submit"> <input type="button" id="CompleteAll" name="CompleteAll" value="Check All" onclick="javascript:checkAll('checklist', true);"><input type="button" id="UncheckAll" name="UncheckAll" value="Uncheck All" onclick="javascript:checkAll('checklist', false);">                  
     <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');"></form>
```

It is populated from the database based on the users session_id, however if the user wants to create a new list item (or is a new visitor period) he can click the button "Add another text input" and a new form element will generate.

All updates to the database need to be done through AJAX\JQUERY and not through a post which will refresh the page.

I really need help on this one. Getting my head around this kind of... Updating method kind of hurts!

Thanks.

Comment: I see a bunch of variations of the same question in the **Related** list in the sidebar. Are you sure none of them answer your question?

Comment: You'd be super damn surprised.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to catch the click of the button. And make sure you stop propagation.

```
$('checklistSubmit').click(function(e) {
    $(e).stopPropagation();

    $.post({
        url: 'checklist.php'
        data: $('#checklist').serialize(),
        dataType: 'html'
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
           $('div.successmessage').html(data);
           //your success callback function
        } 
        error: function() {
           //your error callback function
        } 
    });
});
```

That's just something I worked up off the top of my head. Should give you the basic idea. I'd be happy to elaborate more if need be.

Check out jQuery's documentation of $.post for all the nitty gritty details.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Edit:

I changed it to use jquery's serialize method. Forgot about it originally.

More Elaboration:

Basically when the submit button is clicked it will call the function specified. You want to do a stop propagation so that the form will not submit by bubbling up the DOM and doing a normal submit.

The $.post is a shorthand version of $.ajax({ type: 'post'});

So all you do is specify the url you want to post to, pass the form data and in php it will come in just like any other request. So then you process the POST data, save your changes in the database or whatever else and send back JSON data as I have it specified. You could also send back HTML or XML. jQuery's documentation shows the possible datatypes.

In your success function will get back data as the first parameter. So whatever you specified as the data type coming back you simply use it how you need to. So let's say you wanted to return some html as a success message. All you would need to do is take the data in the success function and place it where you wanted to in the DOM with .append() or something like that.

Clear as mud?

Comment: If you would elaborate some more, I will be eternally in your debt sir.

Comment: So how would this all work, then with the form elements? What would the MYSQL insert statement look like for something like this.. And I assume I'd need to post it to a separate page right? How do I link it to my processor.php page?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the form elements? They would be in the $_POST variable when you get to the server side code. So if your url was 'processor.php' you would just access $_POST in there and access the fields by name. Then after avoid SQL injection by escaping values and what not you just build your insert statement for mysql to save the record(s) to the database.

Comment: Yea, it makes more sense.. I'm just scrambling to find working examples that kind of fit the specific needs of my form to illustrate what you're telling me. I see the building blocks you've provided now im trying to fill in the blanks..

Comment: Ok. Well I have found that sometimes I just have to get started with what I have and the other pieces seem to fall into place later. I would start by simply getting your javascript posting to the server and having the server just send a simple response back. Then worry about saving to the database, and if you can't figure it out after that, come back and post another question. That's just me though.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i post form data using jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    type: 'GET',
    data: $('#checklist').serialize(),
    cache: false,
}).done(function (response) {
    /* It worked */
}).fail(function () {
    /* It didnt worked */
});
```

Hope this helps, let me know how you get on!

Answer (score 1):

You need two scripts here: one that runs the AJAX (better to use a framework, jQuery is one of the easiest for me) and a PHP script that gets the Post data and does the database update.

I'm not going to give you a full source (because this is not the place for that), but a guide. In jQuery you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { // DOM is ready
    $("form#checklist").submit(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault(); // Avoid the "submit" to work, we'll do this manually
        var data = new Array();
        var dynamicInputs = $("input,select", $(this)); // All inputs and selects in the scope of "$(this)" (the form)

        dynamicInputs.each(function() {
            // Here "$(this)" is every input and select
            var object_name = $(this).attr('name');
            var object_value = $(this).attr('value');
            data[object_name] = object_value; // Add to an associative array
        });

        // Now data is fully populated, now we can send it to the PHP
        // Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
        $.post("http://localhost/script.php", data, function(response) {
            alert('The PHP returned: ' + response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Then take the values from $_POST in PHP (or any other webserver scripting engine) and do your thing to update the DB. Change the URL and the data array to your needs.

Remember that data can be like this: { input1 : value1, input2 : value2 } and the PHP will get something like $_POST['input1'] = value1 and $_POST['input2'] = value2.

Comment: Ok I'm getting a response from this code.. But it will not post correctly, it blows up. hrm.

Comment: ...And it's because there's no _POST data.

Comment: Try using another selector on var dynamicInputs = $("input,select", $(this));. I didn't test this, just typed from my mind. But you get the idea :)

Comment: Man I have been working on this thing for over 12 hours with almost no breaks at this point lol. My brain is practically fried.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It's been a while since I scripted in JS/jQuery. Maybe it's a problem with var data = new Array();, from what I can remember, it uses the object notation var data = { key1 : "value 1", key2 : "value2" };, but I can't remember if those two are the same. Just try. Try var data = $("form#checklist").serialize(); too! (and you'll not require the dynamicInputs array part).